# NSAppearance is not updating when toggling dark mode

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur, nsstatusbar, macos-darkmode

I have a macOS app that runs only in the macOS status bar. I changed the "Application is agent (UIElement)" property in the Info.plist to "YES":

```xml
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

I have a timer that prints out the appearance's name every 5 seconds like this:

```swift
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { _ in
    let appearance = NSAppearance.currentDrawing()
    print(appearance.name)
}
```

#### Problem

The name doesn't actually change when I toggle dark/light mode in system settings. It always prints the name of the appearance that was set when the application launched.

Is there a way to listen to system appearance changes?

#### Goal

My end goal is actually to draw an `NSAttributedString` to an `NSImage`, and use that `NSImage` as the `NSStatusItem` button's image.

```swift
let image: NSImage = // generate image
statusItem.button?.image = image
```

For the text in the attributed string I use `UIColor.labelColor` that is supposed to be based on the system appearance. However it seems to not respect the system appearance change.

When I start the application in Dark Mode and then switch to Light Mode:

[image: dark-1]
[image: dark-2]

When I start the application in Light Mode and then switch to Dark Mode:

[image: light-1]
[image: light-2]

#### Side note

*The reason why I turn the `NSAttributedString` into an `NSImage` and don't use the `NSAttributedString` directly on the `NSStatusItem` button's `attributedTitle` is because [it doesn't position correctly in the status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65167179/1752496).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with drawing a `NSAttributedString` is, that `NSAttributedString` doesn't know how to render dynamic colors such as `NSColor.labelColor`. Thus, it doesn't react on appearance changes. You have to use a UI element.

#### Solution

I solved this problem by passing the `NSAttributedString` to a `NSTextField` and draw that into an `NSImage`. Works perfectly fine.

```swift
func updateStatusItemImage() {

    // Use UI element: `NSTextField`
    let attributedString: NSAttributedString = ...
    let textField = NSTextField(labelWithAttributedString: attributedString)
    textField.sizeToFit()

    // Draw the `NSTextField` into an `NSImage`
    let size = textField.frame.size
    let image = NSImage(size: size)
    image.lockFocus()
    textField.draw(textField.bounds)
    image.unlockFocus()

    // Assign the drawn image to the button of the `NSStatusItem`
    statusItem.button?.image = image
}
```

#### React on NSAppearance changes

In addition, since `NSImage` doesn't know about `NSAppearance` either I need to trigger a redraw on appearance changes by observing the `effectiveAppearance` property of the button of the `NSStatusItem`:

```swift
observation = statusItem.observe(\.button?.effectiveAppearance, options: []) { [weak self] _, _ in
    // Redraw 
    self?.updateStatusItemImage()
}
```