# Misaligned NSAttributedString in macOS NSStatusItem's button

Tags: macos, nsattributedstring, macos-big-sur, nsstatusitem

I would like to display a two-line `NSAttributedString` as the button title of the `NSStatusItem` of my macOS app.
However, it seems to move the text up a few pixels and, thus, cut it off. This problem did not occur before macOS Big Sur.

[image: actual]

#### Workaround

With some effort I managed to generate an `NSImage` of the text and use it as the button's image.

[image: expected]

#### Question

Is there any way to position the `NSAttributedString` correctly without using an image?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to workaround this problem, but I don’t know if this way is correct, the code with Objetive-C is as follows

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
CGFloat minMaxLineHeight = (font.pointSize - font.ascender + font.capHeight);
[style setMinimumLineHeight:minMaxLineHeight];
[style setMaximumLineHeight:minMaxLineHeight];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, text.length);
[attriString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                       value:style
                       range:range];
[attriString addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName
                       value:@(-3.5)
                       range:range];
```